# lowercase with Jade template

Tags: node.js, templates, filter, pug

I'm using jade in a `nodejs` project

Can't find how to define filters

I have categories that i want to display in a select box, lowercase option values and uppercase option text

```
select
  each cat in categories
    option(value="lowercase(#{cat})") uppercase(#{cat})
```

any idea ?

Answer (score 12):

Why are you not using the native JavaScript functions to do so?

```
select
  each cat in categories
    option(value=cat.toLowerCase())= cat.toUpperCase()
```

Comment: Did you try it? Afaik you can also us `cat`. This is how I am doing it. You did recognize the `=` after the bracket, right?

Comment: Glad I could help. Please accept the answer as correct if it suits you right.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use:

```
select
  each cat in categories
    option(value=#{cat.toLowerCase()}) #{cat.toUpperCase()}
```